# Can I use different fonts sizes for newtxtext and newtxmath?

Tags: amsmath, fontsize

Using amsmath and the new version of txfont, I find they are separately loaded.
Can I set the math to, say, 11.5pt if the text is set to 10.95pt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for any fonts latex has a standard command with default usage setting being

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xiipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

so

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{11.5}{7.5}{5.5}
```

would say to use 11.5pt (and 7.5 and 6.5pt in script and scriptscript sizes) if the text size is 10.95pt (`\@xipt` is 10.95)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=2]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Text and $math$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you'd want something smaller, perhaps 1.05 would do:

```
1.05 * 10.95 = 11.4975
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=1.05]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

Text and $math$

\fontname\font

\fontname\textfont2

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [hmm](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10.5+*+10.95+%3D+11.4975)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it better now?